# achartengine: X title alignment

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

Been searching on this topic but could not find the answer for it. Is it possible to set the X Title alignment in achartengine? I would like to make X Title to align to the right. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: No, nothing to do that , may be you have to change lib source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think there is no alignment option for setXTitle. add some space before the string.

```
mRenderer.setXTitle("              time(sec)");
```

Comment: That's a shame because X Title would be best right aligned I think. Can anyone confirm that there is no way to align X Title? Cheers.